# Oracle- Left outer join on multiple tables not returning desired null values

Tags: oracle, join

I have 3 tables, CAL,SOURCE,HISTORY.

> `CAL TABLE
>   CAL_DATE
>   01/05/16
>   02/05/16
>   03/05/16
>   04/05/16
>   05/05/16
>   06/05/16
>   07/05/16`
>
> `SOURCE TABLE 
>   TABLE_ID    GROUP
>   1210    Sales
>   1211    Reference
>   1230    Marketing
>   1245    Sales
>   1650    Reference
>   1784    Sales`
>
> `HISTORY
>
>   RUN_DATE    TABLE_ID    STATUS
>   01/05/16    1210    COMPLETED
>   02/05/16    1210    COMPLETED
>   02/05/16    1211    COMPLETED
>   03/05/16    1211    COMPLETED
>   01/05/16    1230    COMPLETED
>   03/05/16    1230    COMPLETED`

Query that i used.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(C.CAL_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy') AS CAL_DATE,TO_CHAR(C.CAL_DATE,'day') AS WDAY,X.* FROM CAL C LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT S.GROUP,S.TABLE_ID,H.RUN_DATE,H.STATUS FROM TABLE S 
    LEFT JOIN HISTORY H
    ON S.TABLE_ID=H.TABLE_ID
    WHERE 1=1 
    AND STATUS='COMPLETED'    
)  X
ON TO_CHAR(C.CAL_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')=TO_CHAR(RUN_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND X.TABLE_ID IN (1210,1211,1230)
WHERE TO_CHAR(C.CAL_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy') <= TO_CHAR('03/05/2016','mm/dd/yyyy')
ORDER BY SOURCE_TABLE_ID ASC
```

Expected output is given below but i am getting different output. When I pass more than 1 table id incodition nulls are filtered out. Please help me to correct the query.

> `CAL_DATE TABLEID Status
>   01/05/16    1210    Completed
>   02/05/16    1210    Completed
>   03/05/16    null    null
>   01/05/16    null    null
>   02/05/16    1211    Completed
>   03/05/16    1211    Completed
>   01/05/16    1230    Completed
>   02/05/16    null    null
>   03/05/16    1230    Completed`

Comment: This query cannot compile nor run, because it references `SOURCE_TABLE_ID` column in this condition:  `X.SOURCE_TABLE_ID IN (1210,1211,1230)`, while a subquery named `X` doesn't contain such a column in the select list: `SELECT S.GROUP,S.TABLE_ID,H.RUN_DATE,H.STATUS FROM ... `

Comment: its my bad. the column name is TABLE_ID only. I misplaced SOURCE_TABLE_ID.

Comment: Here is the executable query.  SELECT TO_CHAR(C.CAL_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy') AS CAL_DATE,TO_CHAR(C.CAL_DATE,'day') AS WDAY,X.* FROM CAL C LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT S.GROUP,S.TABLE_ID,H.RUN_DATE,H.STATUS FROM TABLE S 
    LEFT JOIN HISTORY H
    ON S.TABLE_ID=H.TABLE_ID
    WHERE 1=1 
    AND STATUS='COMPLETED'    
)  X
ON TO_CHAR(C.CAL_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')=TO_CHAR(RUN_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND X.TABLE_ID IN (1210,1211,1230)
WHERE TO_CHAR(C.CAL_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy') <= TO_CHAR('03/05/2016','mm/dd/yyyy')
ORDER BY TABLE_ID,CAL_DATE ASC

Answer (score 2):

You need to gain a better understanding how a LEFT JOIN works (outer joins in general - left/right and full [outer] join)
The LEFT JOIN is always performed in two steps:

```
SELECT ....
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table1 ON join_conditions
WHERE where_conditions
```

Step 1 - the LEFT JOIN is performed first (using conditions specified in ON clause to join two tables)
Step 2 - the WHERE conditions is applied to a resulset generated by the join in step 1

How the LEFT JOIN works - a quick reminder: LEFT JOIN returns always ALL rows from the left table, even these rows for which there is no match in the right table. When there is no match (the ON condition evaluates to false), LEFT JOIN returns NULLs for the right table.
The RIGHT JOIN works in the same way, but it returns all rows from the RIGHT table, not the left one as LEFT JOIN.

---

SO if you have this query:

```
SELECT S.GROUP,S.TABLE_ID,H.RUN_DATE,H.STATUS 
FROM source_table S 
LEFT JOIN HISTORY H
ON S.TABLE_ID=H.TABLE_ID
WHERE H.STATUS='COMPLETED'
```

the database first performs the LEFT JOIN, that is:

```
SELECT S.GROUP,S.TABLE_ID,H.RUN_DATE,H.STATUS 
FROM source_table S 
LEFT JOIN HISTORY H
ON S.TABLE_ID=H.TABLE_ID
```

The above query gives the following result (notice NULLs in the last 3 rows on the rigth side):

```
|   S.GROUP | S.TABLE_ID |                 H.RUN_DATE |  H.STATUS |
|-----------|------------|----------------------------|-----------|
|     Sales |       1210 |  January, 05 2016 00:00:00 | COMPLETED |
|     Sales |       1210 | February, 05 2016 00:00:00 | COMPLETED |
| Reference |       1211 | February, 05 2016 00:00:00 | COMPLETED |
| Reference |       1211 |    March, 05 2016 00:00:00 | COMPLETED |
| Marketing |       1230 |  January, 05 2016 00:00:00 | COMPLETED |
| Marketing |       1230 |    March, 05 2016 00:00:00 | COMPLETED |
|     Sales |       1245 |                     (null) |    (null) |
| Reference |       1650 |                     (null) |    (null) |
|     Sales |       1784 |                     (null) |    (null) |
```

And then the database performs the WHERE condition on the above resultset:

```
WHERE H.STATUS='COMPLETED'
```

Since `NULL='COMPLETED'` evaluates to FALSE, then the final result of the query is:

```
|     GROUP | TABLE_ID |                   RUN_DATE |    STATUS |
|-----------|----------|----------------------------|-----------|
|     Sales |     1210 |  January, 05 2016 00:00:00 | COMPLETED |
|     Sales |     1210 | February, 05 2016 00:00:00 | COMPLETED |
| Reference |     1211 | February, 05 2016 00:00:00 | COMPLETED |
| Reference |     1211 |    March, 05 2016 00:00:00 | COMPLETED |
| Marketing |     1230 |  January, 05 2016 00:00:00 | COMPLETED |
| Marketing |     1230 |    March, 05 2016 00:00:00 | COMPLETED |
```

that is: all NULLs were skipped.
See this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2ed0/3

---

If you want to get also records with NULL values, you need to change this condition to:

```
WHERE ( H.STATUS='COMPLETED' OR H.STATUS IS NULL )
```

you can also remove ths condition from the WHERE clause, and add it to the ON condition of the LEFT JOIN, that is:

```
SELECT S.GROUP,S.TABLE_ID,H.RUN_DATE,H.STATUS 
FROM source_table S 
LEFT JOIN HISTORY H
ON ( S.TABLE_ID=H.TABLE_ID AND H.STATUS='COMPLETED' )
```

see the last query in this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2ed0/3

Comment: Very nice explanation of the WHERE clause turns my LEFT into an INNER join problem. as an aside I have a pretty strong preference for moving the filter to the on rather than the OR... IS NULL.