# SQLite constraint inside on-clause not working

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQL#1

```
select doc.doc_id, doc.content, link, words.words 
from doc left join words 
on doc.doc_id = words.doc_id and words.words = "foo" and doc.doc_id < 1538766632412
where doc.content like "%foo%" and words.words is null
order by doc.doc_id desc limit 10
```

SQL#2

```
select doc.doc_id, doc.content, link, words.words 
from doc left join words 
on doc.doc_id = words.doc_id and words.words = "foo"
where doc.content like "%foo%" and words.words is null  and doc.doc_id < 1538766632412
order by doc.doc_id desc limit 10
```

**Outcome from SQL#1 doesn't take "doc.doc_id < 1538766632412" into account.** But the constraint does work in SQL#2. And I find out in SQLite doc that, "If there is an ON clause then the ON expression is evaluated for each row of the cartesian product as a boolean expression. Only rows for which the expression evaluates to true are included from the dataset." The expression should return false on such records in SQL#1 according to the DOC.

**What is the reason behind this?** Or how could I google on this topic?
Thank.

Comment: update  your question and add  a proper data sample  .. and the expected  result

Comment: You're looking for the definition of "left join" or "left outer join". We're not talking about *constraints* here; *constraints* mean something else in relational and SQL databases. We're talking about the *join condition*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle- Left outer join on multiple tables not returning desired null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166223/oracle-left-outer-join-on-multiple-tables-not-returning-desired-null-values)

Answer (score 2):

This is your first query, structured a bit differently:

```
select d.doc_id, d.content, ?.link, w.words 
from doc d left join
     words w
     on d.doc_id = w.doc_id and w.words = 'foo' and
        d.doc_id < 1538766632412
where d.content like '%foo%; and w.words is null
order by d.doc_id desc
limit 10;
```

What I see is the condition on `d.doc_id < 1538766632412` in the `on` clause -- and `d` is the first table in the `left join`.

How do `left join`s work?  The join produces every row in the first table along with every row in the second table that matches each first table row.  If there are no rows in the second table, then `NULL` values are returned.  This set is then filtered by the `where` clause.

What does this mean?  If the `on` clause returns `false` or `null`, *the row from the first table is still returned*.  Let me repeat that:  *all* rows in the first table are returned *regardless* of the outcome of the `on` clause.  Direct consequence:  Filters on the first table in the `on` clause for a `left join` have no effect (well, they will return `NULL` values for the columns from the second table).

So, all such filtering should be in the `where` clause.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks a lot. I did come back to the doc to check that part in order to understand why I misunderstood that. It says "...for each row in the original left-hand input dataset that corresponds to no rows at all in the composite dataset (if any)." I thought "corresponds" only refers to those linkages with values from both sides. But it is talking the entire on-clause. It makes more senses in current implementation. Your explanation on this, especially the second part, helps a lot on understanding this.